# Unity (2019.3.12f1) не билдит apk

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Скачал я новую версию unity (2019.3.12f1) и я не могу билдить apk. В консоле много непонятных ошибок, а на старой версии (2019.3.11f1) пишет: вы не используете рекомендованную версию unity и тоже не билдит. Что делать? Может это новый баг? Если кто-то сталкивался и исправил ошибку, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: приложите ошибки хоть какие-то

Comment: 1)FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 2) * Where: 3) Build file 'C:\Users\������\Documents\game\Dumpocalypse\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3) * What went wrong: 4) A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'. 5)> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] 6) * Try:  7) BUILD FAILED in 1s

Comment: Там даже написано: путь проекта содержит не ASCII символы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в пути проекта, ошибка выглядит так:

```
Error:(1, 0) Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details.

This warning can be disabled by using the command line flag -Dcom.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true, or adding the line 'com.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
```

решить проблему можно добавив строку в `gradle.properties`:

```
android.overridePathCheck=true
```

как и сказано в сообщении:

```
This warning can be disabled by using 
the command line flag -Dcom.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true,
 or adding the line 
'com.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true'
 to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
```

так же я вам советую переместить проект в директорию без кириллицы.

P.S. В вопрос нужно добавлять ошибку текстом, а не картинкой :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: Да хорошо, спасибо!